# How can i view the live stream i'm publishing via expression encoder SDK on wpf from another computer?

Tags: c#, wpf, ip-address, live-streaming, expression-encoder-sdk

So i have a lack of knowledge issue with this.

I'm currently streaming my webcam and trying to do a small conferencing application on WPF. I can easily see the streamed video by doing `<MediaElement Name="VideoControl" Source="http://localhost:8080"/>` on my computer.

But i don't know what to write instead of `http://localhost:8080` on an external computer because of my lack of knowledge. I've tried to write my external ip address, i've tried to write my local network ip with a computer on the same network. None of them has worked.

To sum up, i need to know how to access my stream from anywhere around the world (wow that sounded extremely like IP).

Here is the code i wrote to broadcast my stream;

```
                _job = new LiveJob();
                EncoderDevice videoDev = null;
                foreach (EncoderDevice ved in EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video))
                    if (ved.Name == VideoDevices.SelectedItem.ToString())
                        videoDev = ved;

                EncoderDevice audioDev = null;
                foreach (EncoderDevice aed in EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio))
                    if (aed.Name == AudioDevices.SelectedItem.ToString())
                        audioDev = aed;

                // preset, editting etc..
                _job.ApplyPreset(LivePresets.VC1HighSpeedBroadband16x9);

                LiveDeviceSource deviceSource = _job.AddDeviceSource(videoDev, audioDev);
                _job.ActivateSource(deviceSource);

                PullBroadcastPublishFormat outputFormat = new PullBroadcastPublishFormat();
                outputFormat.BroadcastPort = 8080;
                outputFormat.MaximumNumberOfConnections = 10;
                _job.PublishFormats.Add(outputFormat);

                _job.StartEncoding();
```

I'm sorry for my bad explanation, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noone ever answered this?

Did you ever get it to work? If you could not open the stream from another computer in your LAN with VLC player, I would think your firewall is the blocker.

Allways when having issues with networking, turn off EVERYTHING so your stuff works, then turn back one and one. That way you get to find out which firewall/setting that is blocking you.

Once you get it to work in LAN, try from a machine outside your home network. Not all routers/modems support rerouting you back into your network if you try to access the external IP of your modem/router from inside your LAN. Your external IP can be found at whatismyip.com or similar sites.

So you will probably have to rely on help from someone else or try out some VPN solution to test conenction to your external address from outside your network.